# Creating an "Extended Bio" Field in the Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress

I have managed to created a couple extra fields in the User Profile page in the admin for Twitter and LinkedIn. However, I would like to create an "Extended Bio" field and an "Introduction" field to appear on the same page but under the "About Yourself" section. If someone could point me in the right direction (a tutorial), I would appreciate it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [WP About Author](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-about-author/) plugin.  You might need to tweak it to make it do exactly as you describe but it should get you about 80% of the way there.